# Suggest PHP Driver for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

I have installed Mongodb 3.2 version, and also have XAMPP 1.7(PHP Version 5.3) please suggest PHP driver for MongoDB.. and how to config that PHP Driver into XAMPP

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/php/

Comment: in my case without Changing PHP version(5.3) what can i do? can i use Mongo 3.0? wher can i download 3.0 version? @Sammaye

Comment: Ah , I actually skipped over 5.3, sorry. Hmm, I am actually not sure, I have not tried it but it isn't officially supported

Comment: Your PHP version is only compatible with an outdated driver, so I would strongly recommend upgrading to PHP 5.4 first and using [this](http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php) one.